# Change Application Name in Settings

Tags: ios, xcode

I am taking over an IOS legacy product written in Objective-C.
Say, the product is called *Foobar*.

To run both the old version and the new version on the iPad, I first called our version of the software "*OurComp Foobar*".

After a while, I was able to present it to our customer and named it back to "*Foobar*".

Now, when I look at the settings in the *IOS user settings*, our application is still listed as "*OurComp Foobar*". I found this after I added some settings which appeared there. Deployment to this device always takes place from xcode directly to the device.

I have **grepped** through the entire source directory, looking for the string "*OurComp*", but it doesn't appear anywhere.

I guess it is linked to the bundle id etc. - but where would I have to change it back?
Once the software will be available to the public, we want to present it as "*Foobar*", not as "*OurComp Foobar*".

Note that this is a question on software development, not on jurisdiction. We are developing the software on behalf of the client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only user facing app name is the CFBundleDisplayName, which you set in the Info.plist. The name on the App Store is a different name and is set via App Store Connect.